# Verifying DMI Pool Data after installing windows 8

Tags: windows-8-preview, dmi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer stuck at “Verifying DMI Pool Data”](https://superuser.com/questions/390932/computer-stuck-at-verifying-dmi-pool-data)

I have installed the windows 8 customer preview and now when I boot it says verifying DMI pool data, i left my computer on overnight and it still says it

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please help me my computer is brocken

Answer (score 0):

> This issue can be caused by any of the below reasons.
>
> Corrupt boot files on the computer.
>
> Settings for hard disk drive are not correct.
>
> Floppy diskette or CD in computer causing issue.
>
> Boot devices not set properly.
>
> BIOS corrupt or misc. setting not set properly.
>
> Connections loose or disconnected.
>
> Bad Hard disk drive or other bad hardware.

.

[Source of Information](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000474.htm)